# How to tell PyDoc to generate documentation to user defined directory

Tags: python, pydoc

PyDoc creates HTML documentation in current directory when generating documentation of modules.
I really need to specify another directory which will be a placeholder for generated documentation instead the directory from which PyDoc is called.

I am using `python -m pydoc -w <MODULES_DIR>` to generate documentation.

Is this possible and if it is, how?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and came across this question trying to figure it out.  I couldn't figure out how to do it either, so this is my solution.  Rather than try to trick pydoc to outputting to a specific location, I'm just generating the documentation in the current directory and moving the files to the location I want.

In my case, the target folder is named 'doc', and the source is located under the 'semlm' directory

```
mkdir -p doc
pydoc -w `find semlm -name '*.py'`
mv *.html doc
```

(You should be able to customize the pydoc command as you wish, but this is what worked for me).

I didn't want to type this all out every time so I put it in a Makefile.  Here is an excerpt:

```
.PHONY: doc

doc:
    mkdir -p doc
    pydoc -w `find semlm -name '*.py'`
    mv *.html doc
```

The `.PHONY: doc` is needed because the Makefile target has the same name as a folder in the top level directory (i.e. 'doc').  Now I can generate documentation into the doc folder by running:

```
make doc
```

Perhaps there is a more elegant way, but this is the best I've found so far.

Answer (score 3):

pydoc -w  ...

Write out the HTML documentation for a module to a file in the current
    directory.  If  contains a '/', it is treated as a filename; if
    it names a directory, documentation is written for all the contents.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in syntax. I am using python -m pydoc -w <MODULES_DIR> but the generated document goes to current directory as I described. But I want that this document to be saved to some other directory. I don't know of any other switch to PyDoc which will produce the effect that I want.

Comment: Does the directory you specify exist? Do you append a / to the end of the directory name?